# Unable to call javascript in CSHTML

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am pretty new to MVC. I am trying to call a javascript function from a view page (button click) but I am unable to call it .I have the javascript function in a seperate file .I have added the reference of the script file in the view page(CSHTML).
Code:

```
  <input type="submit" value="enter" onclick="IsFirstNameEmpty();">
```

Javascript Function

```
function IsFirstNameEmpty() {
    if (document.getElementById('TxtFName').value == "") {
        return 'First Name should not be empty';
    }
    else { return ""; }
}
```

Comment: TXTFName is a textbox ID..any thoughts?

Comment: You try to return some text value. Should it be like alert or what?

Comment: Your code should work fine. Working sample here http://jsbin.com/zipanubuna/edit?html,js,output. you probably want to change the return to `alert('some message');`

Comment: I was just testing .It could be an alert or something else.

Comment: thanks guys .Got it when I used alert statement.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example : https://jsfiddle.net/8mhuL839/

You do everything fine (I trust your words about You've correctly included js-file). But You just doesn't do anything with your returned string.

In my example I just put text into alert-dialog.
Maybe you want to show this text in some label, then just do next :

```
document.getElementById('LblValidation').value = returnedText;
```

where `LblValidation` is Id of some Label that will contains your string, and `returnedText` is string that you try to return from your function.

```html
 <input type="submit" value="enter" onclick="IsFirstNameEmpty();"/>
 <input type="text" value="text" id="TxtFName" />
 
 <script type="text/javascript" >
 function IsFirstNameEmpty() {
    if (document.getElementById('TxtFName').value == "") {
        alert( 'First Name should not be empty');
    }
    else { alert(""); }
}
 </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

In general, there is no difference between what you did without the mvc paradigm. Pay only attention to the fact that if the script is inside a partial page it could be executed more than once or not in the moment you expect (for example you could call a function before it is defined because of the partial views loading order). In this simple scenario, I think you have just to be sure that the script containing the definition of the function is really included in the resulting web page. The simplest way to do this is by checking the page source in the browser.